# Java spring / spring boot Application : Web logic to Tomcat conversion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, weblogic

I am asked to convert the existing Java spring / spring boot Application that runs on Web logic to Tomcat. I understood that dependencies need to be updated and main class needs an update. However I don't have the checklist for the Tomcat migration, hope someone could have gone through the same migration process and documented.

Can you please assist with the checklist / process to be followed for migrating the existing Java spring / spring boot Application that runs on Web logic to Tomcat?

Comment: Actually you don’t need do anything excepting producing a war instead of jar - you configure that in Pom.xml https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Answer (score 1):

Web logic to Tomcat conversion for spring boot application takes few steps like:

1. Change in dependencies.
2. Change in servletinitializer
3. Deployment : generate jar/war file

Below is checklist

[image]

To get the things done in proper way I recommend you to visit the below post :

https://dev.to/varshithv/migration-of-java-spring-boot-applications-from-weblogic-to-tomcat-server-jpd